# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: notFound() is not allowed to use in root layout

Tags: http-status-code-404, next.js13

Getting the error *Unhandled Runtime Error Error: notFound() is not allowed to use in root layout*

next js 13 with app directory (v 13.4.12)

Importing notFound :

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
```

Then using it in my function, which when the user does enter a route that is not vaild or returned it goes to 404.

```
  // Throw 404 if user requests invalid project
  if (!project) {
    return notFound();
  }
```

However the error: *Unhandled Runtime Error Error: notFound() is not allowed to use in root layout* occurs.

Anyone having the same issue with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found#notfound):

> Invoking the `notFound()` function throws a `NEXT_NOT_FOUND` error and terminates rendering of the route segment in which it was thrown. **Specifying a `not-found` file** allows you to gracefully handle such errors by rendering a Not Found UI within the segment.

So you need to create a `not-found.js` file in your page's or it's parent directories (if you want it to be shared by other children pages)

```
//not-found.js
import Link from 'next/link'
 
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
      <p>Could not find requested resource</p>
      <Link href="/">Return Home</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Using notFound() paired with a not-found.tsx works fine, but that is not the point with pages this used to route to next js's default 404 but here it runs that layout error?

Unless in app dir all routes need to contain their own not-found? Seems a bit pointless

Comment: @Alex There is no default 404 page in `nextjs13` (at least not yet). this new app stucture works like a tree. Any `not-found.js` file will work for it's containing page and all routes that are under that segment. This way you can have multiple customized 404 pages in your app.

Comment: It appears this has been fixed in the latest version of next js  "next": "^13.4.13" as the default next js 404 is showing correctly on call of notFound().

However, if you want a custom 404 @Hamed is correct in how to do this :)